# Mocked EF DbSet will not re-enumerate with async calls

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-core

source code here: https://github.com/chrishayescodes/efbug

if I create dummy DbSets using the technique found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking
i can only enumerate the in-memory collection once

i have a db call that looks like this:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetCPeople(IMyContext context)
{
    var regex = new Regex("^[Cc]");
    // pay special attention to this non-blocking call
    var dbpeople = (await context.People.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
    var peopleWhosNameStartsWithC =
        dbpeople
        .Where(p => regex.IsMatch(p.FirstName));
    return peopleWhosNameStartsWithC;
}
```

and I have a unit test:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        IMyContext _context;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
            var dummyData = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person{Id=1, FirstName="Chris",LastName="Johnson"},
                new Person{Id=2, FirstName="Sally",LastName="Sue"},
            };
            var mockPersonSet = EntityFrameworkMockHelper.GetMockDbSet<Person>(dummyData);
            var mockContext = new Mock<IMyContext>();
            mockContext.Setup(x => x.People).Returns(mockPersonSet.Object);
            _context = mockContext.Object;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // the first enumeration will work correctly
            var a = MyDb.GetCPeople(_context).Result;
            Assert.IsTrue(a.Any(), "a Records Exist");
            Assert.IsTrue(a.Count() == 1, "a Only One Record");
            Assert.IsTrue(a.First().FirstName == "Chris", "a Record is the one with 'Chris' as first name");
            var b = MyDb.GetCPeople(_context).Result;
            // the second enumeration will return 0 results
            Assert.IsTrue(b.Any(),"b Records Exist");
            Assert.IsTrue(b.Count() == 1, "b Only One Record");
            Assert.IsTrue(b.First().FirstName == "Chris", "b Record is the one with 'Chris' as first name");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            var cstr = "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Contacts;Integrated Security=SSPI";
            // if i go to a real database the method works fine
            var context = new MyRealContext(cstr);
            var a = MyDb.GetCPeople(context).Result;
            Assert.IsTrue(a.Any(), "a Records Exist");
            Assert.IsTrue(a.Count() == 1, "a Only One Record");
            Assert.IsTrue(a.First().FirstName == "Chris", "a Record is the one with 'Chris' as first name");
            var b = MyDb.GetCPeople(context).Result;
            Assert.IsTrue(b.Any(), "b Records Exist");
            Assert.IsTrue(b.Count() == 1, "b Only One Record");
            Assert.IsTrue(b.First().FirstName == "Chris", "b Record is the one with 'Chris' as first name");
        }
    }
```

`TestMethod1` will NOT work, the second enumeration will return 0/ZERO results

`TestMethod2` WILL work, it connects to a REAL db and get's the records each time.

Comment: @Dai I didn't consider this a bug...??? I thought maybe there was an issue with the implementation. The repo was set to private, I changed it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the mock implementation

https://github.com/chrishayescodes/efbug/blob/master/TestProject1/TestProject1/UnitTest1.cs#L107

```
dbSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>>()
            .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
            .Returns(new DbAsyncEnumerator<T>(queryable.GetEnumerator()));
```

The `Returns` call should return a factory delegate, not a static object

```
dbSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>>()
            .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
            .Returns(()=>
            new DbAsyncEnumerator<T>(queryable.GetEnumerator()));
```